# SQLJ in Netbeans

Tags: oracle, netbeans, db2, sqlj

I just read, that Netbeans does not support SQLJ and can´t believe this. Is there really no way to run SQLJ code in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

In recent times NetBeans has native compatibility with Maven.  There is a [SQLJ maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sqlj-maven-plugin/index.html) available that can help you work with SQLJ via Maven (and therefore NetBeans).  Essentially this plugin is a wrapper around IBM's SQLJ generator.

I'm no expert on SQLJ but from the age of the SQLJ tutorials on the net, the time of using SQLJ seems to have passed and it would seem to be rarely used nowadays.

I was able to download the Maven plugin source code but unfortunately I was not able to acquire an SQLJ translator as the IBM translator did not appear to be publically accessible.  I understand Oracle also produced an SQLJ generator but I imagine this is similarly difficult to get hold of.

Comment: SQLJ is part of DB2, and you can download DB2 express-C edition, that is free at no charge. You can use SQLJ and develop your programs with this basic edition. The fact that is not popular, it does not mean that SQLJ is obsolete, it is just a technology not very popular, that offers a lot of advantages compared to pure JDBC with dynamic SQL. I hope you understand the beneficts of static SQL and the packages in the database.